# Plotting multiple X variables for one continuous Y variable in a single plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, rbind, melt

I am trying to draw a line plot having two `x` variables in the `x-axis` with one continuous `y` variable in the `y-axis`. The count of `x1` and `x2` are different. The `df` looks like the following-

`df <- structure(list(val = c(3817,2428,6160,6729,7151,7451,6272,7146,7063,6344,5465,6169,7315,6888,7167,6759,4903,6461,7010,7018,6920,3644,6541,31862,31186,28090,28488,29349,28284,25815,23529,20097,19945,22118), type = c("1wt", "1wt", "3wt", "3wt", "3wt", "5wt", "5wt", "7wt", "7wt", "7wt","10wt","10wt","10wt","15wt","15wt","20wt","20wt","25wt","25wt","25wt","30wt","30wt","30wt","20m","20m","15m","15m","15m","10m","10m","5m", "5m", "5m", "5m"), group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")), row.names = c(NA, 34L), class = "data.frame")`

where the `x` variables are-

`x1 <- factor(df$type, levels = c("1wt", "3wt", "5wt", "7wt", "10wt", "15wt", "20wt", "25wt", "30wt"))` *and*

`x2 <- factor(df$type, levels = c("20m", "15m","10m","5m"))`

I want to have separate lines for the `x1` and `x2` with different colors and legends as per the `df$group` at the x-axis with `df$val` at the y -axis. could you please help me doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried replicating but `x1` and `x2` are `NA`s. please check your code again.

Comment: and please explain what type of plot are you trying to produce: scatter? histogram? bars?

Comment: *I am trying to draw a line plot* ... please post your plotting attempt.

Comment: It's unclear to me from the question what the goal is. If we're using `df` as provided, with some adaptation of `type` on the x-axis and `val` on the y-axis, the first two lines of `df` show two `val` numbers (3817 and 2428) associated with the same type (1wt). Do you want to show a vertical line here, or is something else intended?

Comment: @JonSpring I want to have a line plot where for both `x1` and `x2` would have their lines for total `y`, that is- within the `val` range in the `y` axis, all `x (x1 &x2)` will fall and probably they will intersect each other. Thank you.

Comment: @Spätzle you will see some `NA's` for `x2` since they have lesser values compared to `x1`, in fact that is my case from which I need to plot them. I want to have line plots (preferably `geom_quantile()/geom_smooth()`) though any other meaningful line plots are okay...thank you

Comment: Could you draw a picture of what you're looking for? It seems like you have 9 different bandwidth categories (where "1mbit" is coded as group A and type "1wt") and 4 different time categories (where "5m" is coded as group B and type "5m"). How are those supposed to be mapped to one overlapping axis? Should "1mbit" be at the same x coordinate as "20m", and "10mbit" (the middle level of bandwidth) be in between "15m" and "10m" (the two middle time catgories)?

Comment: hey @JonSpring, actually my `x1` suppose to be `wt` not `mbit` (which I corrected-sorry about that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: added below**

Here's an approach that assumes the intent is to map the span of possible type values from group A against the span of possible values from group B.

Labeling could be added manually, but I don't think there's any simple way to use two categorical x axes together in one plot.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(x = case_when(type == "1wt" ~ 0,
                       type == "3wt" ~ 1,
                       type == "5wt" ~ 2,
                       type == "7wt" ~ 3,
                       type == "10wt" ~ 4,
                       type == "15wt" ~ 5,
                       type == "20wt" ~ 6,
                       type == "25wt" ~ 7,
                       type == "30wt" ~ 8,

                       type == "20m"  ~ 0/3 * 8,
                       type == "15m"  ~ 1/3 * 8,
                       type == "10m"  ~ 2/3 * 8,
                       type == "5m"   ~ 3/3 * 8))


ggplot(df2, aes(x, val, color = group, group = group)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm)
```

[image]

**2nd approach**

It sounds like the OP would like to use the `type` values numerically in some fashion. If they aren't intrinsically linked to each other in the way that's described, I suspect it will be misleading to plot them as if they are. (See [here](https://blog.datawrapper.de/dualaxis/) for a discussion of why this is trouble.)

That said, here's how you could do it. First, here's an approach that just uses the numeric portion of `type` as is. Note that "m", associated with group B, is on the bottom and "wt" is on the top, associated with group A, as in the example added in the OP comment below. I've added colors to the axes to clarify this. It's a little counterintuitive visually, since the points related to the top axis are on the bottom, and vice versa.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  # First, let's take the number used in "type" without adjustment
  mutate(x_unadj = parse_number(type))

ggplot(df2, aes(x_unadj, val, color = group, group = group)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm) + # Feel free to use other smoothing method, but
                             # not obvious to me what would be improvement.
  scale_x_continuous("m", sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = "wt")) +
  theme(axis.text.x.bottom  = element_text(color = "#00BFC4"),
        axis.title.x.bottom = element_text(color = "#00BFC4"),
        axis.text.x.top     = element_text(color = "#F8766D"),
        axis.title.x.top    = element_text(color = "#F8766D"))
```

[image]

If this is not satisfactory, we might reverse the order of both axes using

```
scale_x_reverse("m", sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = "wt")) +
```

[image]

Using ggplot 3.1.0 (from Oct 2018), I could not get the secondary x axis to shift in the opposite direction as the primary axis. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46855643/ggplot2-reversing-secondary-continuous-x-axis) from 2017 doesn't seem to work with this version any more. As of Dec 2018, there is a [proposed fix](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/3040) being reviewed that is meant to address this.

Comment: Thank you @JonSpring for this. I did not get how you calculated the `type == "15m"  ~ 8/3, type == "10m"  ~ 2*8/3, type == "5m"   ~ 8` specifically `dividing by 3 and again multiplying`. This link (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUCgb.png) is an example what I want to have with simple lines not actually the `lm`, if possible. Basically my aim is to plot `x1 & x2` in respect to all `df$val (that includes all values for group A & B- should range from min at the bottom to max at the top)` in the `y` axis or they can be plotted as `y1` and `y2` on both sides may be. I really appreciate your time.